# Pandas Dataframe Append or Set_Value

Tags: python, append, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through a list which includes some numbers and wanted to save to a Dataframe.

However after trying `set_values` and `concat` (which is even more difficult). I am not able to get a suitable resolution. The other problem is that it has to stop before reading "END"...

The list and DataFrame are given below:

```
words= ['302', '1208', '1208', '0', '179', '1208', '1208', '0', '904', '233', '233', '0', '***END', 'OF', 'REPORT***']

dd = pd.DataFrame(columns=("AA","BB","CC","DD"))
```

And the code which I had used till now:

```
for r in range(40,48,4):
    for s in range(41,49,4):
        for t in range(42,50,4):
            for z in range(43,51,4):
                dd = dd.set_value(len(dd),'AA',words[r])
                dd = dd.set_value(len(dd),'BB',words[s])
                dd = dd.set_value(len(dd),'CC',words[t])
                dd = dd.set_value(len(dd),'DD',words[z])
```

I want to return something like below:

```
AA | BB | CC | DD |    
302|1208|1208|0   |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, `concat` is a last resort. It can get unavoidably hairy. And, for what it's worth, I don't think I've ever used `set_value` -- it is rarely necessarily to get so granular.

Here's one solution.

```
In [10]: numbers = np.array(words[:words.index('***END')]).astype('int')

In [11]: columns = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']

In [12]: dd = DataFrame(numbers.reshape(-1, 4), columns=columns)

In [13]: dd
Out[13]: 
    AA    BB    CC  DD
0  302  1208  1208   0
1  179  1208  1208   0
2  904   233   233   0
```

(If that `-1` is new to you, see the [documentation for reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape).)

Comment: Agreed... and if you're using a for loop you're probably doing it wrong. :)

Comment: very neat and elegant approach. Will be a big win over traditional software versed in reading and storing data from space or comma separated files.